# Dagre layout for simple tree in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js, dagre

How to use dagre layout in cytoscape.js to draw a simple tree. I am putting    layout{ name: 'dagre'} and added dagre.js file from https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre/blob/master/dist/dagre.js.
It is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the similar problem. I've used dagre.js from cytoscape package (https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/lib/dagre.js) and its working fine.

It seems like cytoscape dagre layout is not compatible with latest dagre.js (https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre) or something like this. It throws error on that line:

```
var g = new dagre.Digraph();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the dagre library bundled with the distribution in the lib folder hosted on GitHub.

[GitHub Link to working Dagre.js for Cytoscape.js](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/lib/dagre.js)

Answer (score 0):

Please post an example.  It works on the debug page and in the docs, so I suspect there's an issue with your code.

Comment: Your answer should be a comment.

Comment: Thanks @maxkfranz Its working now. Used    https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/lib/dagre.js for dagre library.